# How do I get the audio output from this website?

Tags: javascript, audio, request

Newbie in javascript here, I'm trying to get the output from a simple text-to-speech site (the URL changes to the file location) and play it. After looking online I tried this:

```
var request = require('request');
function tts(text) {
    var r = request.get(`https://tts.cyzon.us/tts?text='${encodeURI(text)}'`, function(err, res, body) {
        let audio = new Audio(r.uri.href);
        audio.play();
    });
}
```

... which didn't work. How do I *actually* do this?

Comment: The output is quite awful... Have you tried using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

Answer (score 0):

audio, video, etc in nodejs can you stored in your db in the form of bytes. You can open a file by creating a [readstream](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream/) and then writing the buffer got from the website to the file.
You can then open the file and play the audio